# Allow Search using Enter key on search kit search form

Tags: search, searchkit

Using search kit we can do Auto-Run and Button Click Search.

[image]

On Button search option, I Need to add functionality to search using Enter key too (just to avoid click button every time and do not want Auto-Run option).

Anybody have idea about this ?